# RibbonComboBox MouseLeave Event doesnt fire

Tags: wpf, combobox, mouse, ribbon

I cant get mouseleave to fire inside a ribboncombobox inside a ribboncontrolgroup inside ribbon tab inside a ribbon.

I have a behavior that on mouse enter opens the dropdown and should close it on mouseleave
except mouseleave doesnt fire I verified this using snoop and by setting a breakpoint on the event.

Any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similiar issue with the border control - and I found an event called, "IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged" - that seemed to fire pretty regularily so I used that.